# map.foreachfeatureatpixel() not working in angular typescript open layers 7

Tags: angular, typescript, openlayers, angular-openlayers, openlayers-7

The code working in normal JavaScript finely but in Typescript (Angular) it was throwing an error that `this.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel()`, `this.map` is undefined and cannot read properties of undefined.

This is my code :

```js
public selected: Collection<Feature<any>> = new Collection();
multiSelectFeatures(): void {
  this.clearInteractions();
  this.ClearSelection();
  if (this.selected instanceof Collection) {
    this.selected.forEach(function (feature) {
      feature.setStyle(undefined);
    });
    this.selected.clear();
  }
  this.map.on("singleclick", this.getmultiplefeaturesatpixel);
}

getmultiplefeaturesatpixel(evt: { pixel: Pixel }): void {
  this.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, (feature): void => {
    if (feature instanceof Feature) {
      const featureArray = this.selected.getArray();
      const selIndex = featureArray.indexOf(feature);
      if (selIndex === -1) {
        this.selected.push(feature);
        console.log(feature);
        // this.selected.getArray().forEach((feat) => feat.setStyle(editOperations.highlightStyle));
      } else {
        this.selected.remove(feature);
        feature.setStyle(undefined);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

I want to select multiple features on the map from onclick event but when i pass the single click event to another function there this.map was not defined and getting error cannot read properties of undefined

Comment: Try `this.map.on("singleclick", this.getmultiplefeaturesatpixel.bind(this));`. The context in which your function gets called might be different, that's why `this` is not what you expect.

Comment: If I try that, I am unable to unbind the click event whenever it was not necessary  I have used this.map.un("singleclick", this.getmultiplefeaturesatpixel.bind(this)); for unbinding but still didn't work @OctavianMărculescu